# Click map in canvas

Tags: canvas, dictionary, mozilla, clicking

I found [this](http://www.rubydesigner.com/blog/click-map-using-html5-canvas) clicking map for canvas, but the problem is, that it doesn't work on Firefox.

Do you know about something like this or how to make it working on Firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a simple Google search I found [this](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-world-map-svg-path-with-kineticjs/) nice HTML5 canvas map that works in Firefox.

Click [here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/labs/html5-canvas-world-map-svg-path-with-kineticjs/index.php) to see it working.

I've created a [jsFiddle](http://goo.gl/A7Mf5) that shows it's working.

[image: The map...]

Comment: thank you. And how can I found, over which state mouse is? For example if I want to write under the map on which state mouse is

Comment: Ask another question for this, and don't forget to mark my answer. Click on **✔**, on left of my answer.

Comment: Ok. As I saw the method, you send. It seems good, but is there any way, how to make function my method in Firefox?

Comment: You have there the full code, you have just to analize it. If I helped you vote up my answer. :-)

Comment: I know that there is full code. But isn´t any easier way, how to make the same efect? For example as I send it with the picture in background... (first post)?

Comment: After finding I found something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948251/click-area-on-sprite-in-canvas    meantime it works...