# Click through transparent area on partially transparent image

Tags: javascript, css, html, svg, png

Given some shape, I would like it to be clickable on its filled parts, and not clickable (thus clicking through to the element behind it) on its transparent parts. Here's an example of a triangle shape:
[image]

Black lines are bounding box lines. I would like to be able to select text, or interact with any element that is within bounding box (green-outlined areas), but not covered with the filled part.

I tried SVG with pointer-events set to every possible value, but it does not seem to work. Preferred solution would make us of html5, css and png image, but every working solution is welcomed.

Comment: I believe you'll find your answer in a previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621305/how-do-i-create-a-click-map-using-the-visable-area-of-a-png-image-with-javascrip

Comment: that previous question links to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948251/click-area-on-sprite-in-canvas

Answer (score 1):

You can add style property

> pointer-event:none

to Image it will help you out through the image

Note: it will work only to modern browsers

Comment: The question is about click-through on transparent areas of an element only. But "pointer-event: none;" makes the entire element click-through.